# Car vibrates when in idle, especially with AC on

Tags: engine, honda, ac, idle, vibration

A few months ago I hit a curb with my automatic 2013 Honda CVR (don't drive tired).  Since then, my car vibrates enough to make me nauseous whenever it is not moving. I got it checked, they said it is most likely caused by a little bit of a bend in the frame, though the frame itself doesn't vibrate much, instead the engine shakes very visibly.

After driving it for a few months I've found some other symptoms, and since I know little about cars it would be great if anyone could use these to give possible causes!

The vibrating gets worse whenever the AC is on, though is still there when it is off.  It ceases mostly whenever it is in park/neutral, and is worse whenever it is in reverse (and stopped).  Also, it gets worse with warmer weather.  I noticed that when stopped if I switch from drive to neutral it will almost completely cease for a short time before coming back (though not as bad since it's in neutral).  Also, there is a fast ticking sound coming from the engine area (don't know if it is the engine), which I don't remember being there before.  I was told by the mechanic that it is normal for cars to make sounds like it.  As I press down the gas the vibration quickly ceases and the ticking sound gets faster until it is indistinguishable.

Please let me know if you can think of a cause, and I would be happy to try anything if it would help diagnose a solution!

Answer (score 1):

more then likely the engine or gearbox mount has become in contact with the frame. Check all the mountings carefully to suss which one is causing the problem

Comment: I vote for a broken engine mount.

Comment: If I have very little knowledge of cars is there say a youtube video you might suggest to describe how to check?  That or should I bring it into a different mechanic or like a body shop?  Thanks!